# Is there a way to apply row level security in servicestack?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Is there a way to apply a light weight row level security.

In essence I want to apply

```
            OrmLiteConfig.SqlExpressionSelectFilter = q =>
            {
                if (q.ModelDef.ModelType.HasInterface(typeof(IRowLevelSecurity)))
                {
                    q.Where<IRowLevelSecurity>(x => x.ClientId == request.ClientId);
                }
            };
```

currently I don't have access to the "request" dto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `OrmLiteConfig` filters are static delegates so they wont be able to access the runtime request context unless it's available from a singleton context in hosts that allow it.

I wouldn't recommend it, but you could use the Request Context to set a variable that you can access in your filter, e.g:

```
GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, dto) => {
    if (dto is IRowLevelSecurity dtoRow)
        RequestContext.Instance.Items["ClientId"] = dtoRow.ClientId;
});

OrmLiteConfig.SqlExpressionSelectFilter = q => {
    var clientId = RequestContext.Instance.Items["ClientId"] as string;
    if (clientId == null) return;
    if (q.ModelDef.ModelType.HasInterface(typeof(IRowLevelSecurity)))
    {
        q.Where<IRowLevelSecurity>(x => x.ClientId == clientId);
    }
};
```

But I'd personally avoid any singleton runtime context access which is fragile, tightly coupled with its external host & poorly testable. To reduce boilerplate I'd instead wrap it in an extension method like:

```
public static class MyOrmLiteUtils
{
    public static SqlExpression<T> From<T>(this IDbConnection db, IRowLevelSecurity dto)
        where T : IRowLevelSecurity
    {
        var q = db.From<T>();
        return q.Ensure(x => x.ClientId == dto.ClientId);
    }
}
```

Which in your Service you can use like you would a normal OrmLite Query, e.g:

```
var q = db.From<Table>(dto);
```

Comment: thanx for the quick reply. My problem with the db.From approach is that it leaves it up to the developer to use the correct from. If he for some reason forgets to use the correct from then it won't apply the filter. I guess what 1 could do is use your recommended from and then have a safety in SqlExpressionSelectFilter  that checks if a clientid filter has been added.

Comment: @Murdock Yep, another (more effort) solution might be to create a C# analyzer that inspects Services with `IRowLevelSecurity` DTOs and make sure they're not calling OrmLite's From APis directly. C# Analyzers might make sense if you want a programmatic strategy for forcing specific dev practices + conventions in your code bases.

Comment: Cool thanx @mythz